Newbie question about line endings in git
Hey there super new to this bear with me, I read some stack overflows and a few posts here and still have a few questions.
So I work alone on both a Windows and Mac machine back and forth. In regards to line endings would setting config autocrlf-input on both machines and EOL=lf in VScode be sufficient to take care of maintaining lf endings in the remote and when pulling onto my windows machine/ making new files?
If I understand it correctly new files in VScode should be lf ending, when pushed to the remote from the windows machine they should be converted to lf and when pulled onto the windows machine they should be lf ?
My only concern is in regards to binary files (jpgs pngs etc)
And I read something somewhere can't find the link about dockerized files and converting back and forth ( which this hopefully avoids?)
It would be nice to also avoid it showing as every line modified if that's a side effect of this but I understand if that's acting a lot.
Apologize for the length and any over simplification and appreciate any help in advance.
Thanks !
I tried core.autocrlf input on Windows and according to git add everything is going as expected, just wondering what would happen in regards to binary files ( would it use the heuristic to determine if it's a binary file or not?)
And any issues it may have with dockerized files ?

My recommendation would be to disable the feature altogether (core.autocrlf=false). No sane code editor in 2024 fails to recognise Unix style line endings, and letting git fiddle with your files will confuse style linters and other tools. I'm not saying it doesn't work, I'm just saying it adds unnecessary complexity.

Git's autocrlf should normally ignore line endings within binary files. If you come across issues, try specifying .gitattributes.

It's safer to choose one form of line endings for your project and leave it. A cross-platform project should stick with LF. I recommend adding an EditorConfig file to your project to auto-configure people's editors to your project's liking.

I'll be the only one working on the project as it's just for learning. Would the safest option then or a safe option be to just use core autocrlf input for both the Mac and windows machines and set VS code to have /n as the EOL (lf) on both machines. That should theoretically set all pushes to the remote to be LF ( they should be lf anyway due to being made in VSCode with it's settings ) and it shouldn't change the LF to crlf on pulling from the repository so I should be covered there ? If I use this solution are there any glaring issues anyone suspects with either binary files or otherwise?

@ÁlvaroGonzález if I totally disable it though I'd be relying just on VScode to create the proper file types then and on check out they shouldn't be changed ( even on the windows machine ?, and the upload shouldn't be changed either ?) I suppose I could audit this with git add to make sure no changes are being made when adding them ? So basically just rely on the code editor at that point ? Would git bash In anyway mess with the line endings if I use that terminal on Windows if you happen to know ?

@schwern sorry meant to tag above

Git should not mangle binary files, but I would not handle this with Git and swapping line endings. Instead, handle it with tools such as EditorConfig to coordinate editor configurations so everyone on the project is using the same newline. Also with Pull Request reviews. Use PRs even for your own code, especially for your own code; you can spot your own mistakes. If the commit has mangled the line endings it will show up as changing all the lines. You can also add a check to your PRs to ensure the line endings are ok.

Forgetting to set EOL style in your editor is a valid concern, but it shouldn't be a problem if you're the only one in the project: setting project defaults is a once off thing. For teams, I'd rather address it with a style linter tool. You can create a pre-commit hook to validate modified files and abort commit if CRLF slips through.
